# Need to modify the list of Keys in a Groovy Map

Tags: groovy

I need to modify the key values from the given map below
Example:

```
Map map= ["abcd":["name":"x", "age":"22"],"xyz":["name":"y", "age":"12"]]
```

Need to modify the key values and my final Map should be like below:

```
Map map= ["modifiedkey":["name":"x", "age":"22"],"someanotherkey":["name":"y", "age":"12"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `collectEntries` method from [Groovy Collections API](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#collectEntries(groovy.lang.Closure)):

```
def defaultTransformation = { String key -> key }
def basicTransformation = { String key -> key.toUpperCase().reverse()
Map transformations = [abcd: basicTransformation, xyz: basicTransformation]

Map map= ["abcd":["name":"x", "age":"22"],"xyz":["name":"y", "age":"12"], "unchanged": ["name": "a", "age": "20"]]

Map newMap = map.collectEntries { [(transformations.getOrDefault(it.key, defaultTransformation).call(it.key)): it.value] }
```

In above example I use `Closure` that defines transformation - it expects single `String` parameter that is taken from current map entry key. As you can see Closure in Groovy is first class citizen, so we can pass it as e.g. a value in map. For this example I have created `transformations` map that defines mappings from old key to a new one. I have also created `defaultTransformation` closure - it will be used if mapping in `transformations` map for given key does not exist.

Running following script will produce `newMap` like this one:

```
[DCBA:[name:x, age:22], ZYX:[name:y, age:12], unchanged:[name:a, age:20]]
```

As you can see:

- `abcd` key was transformed using `basicTransformation` closure
- `xyz` key was also transformed using `basicTransformation` closure
- `unchanged` key stayed the same, because there was no mapping in `transformations` map defined and the default one was used - a closure that returns key as is.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your answer,
I need to modify the keys dynamically, like need to get the old key "abcd " and alter the key with some functions like(example: trim,or substring and this key should be new key for the map

Comment: @Raju thanks for providing more details. I have updated my answer with `Closure` support for defining transformation functions using Groovy closures.

Comment: @Raju Please add those requirements to the question then. As of now it reads like you want a simple mapping.

Comment: @Raju Did we help you solve your problem? Is there anything else we can help you with?